# Change color of button when file was add

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want change background color of button, when file was add. How i can do that?
I have such html in my template

```
<form action="/" method="post" multiple>
    <input type="file" name="filename[]">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

My question is: How change bg color for input with type file when files was choosen

Answer (score 2):

You can use label for input file, try this:

```js
function test(button) {
  $(button).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label style="cursor: pointer;">
    <input style="display: none;" type="file" onchange="test(this);" />
    Click me
</label>
```